What integral is used to calculate the electric field generated by a continuous charged curve?
I'm studying Multivariable Mathematics, by Ted Shifrin, in which one reads that ''the gravitational force exerted by a continuous mass distribution $\Omega$ with density function $\delta$ is
$$\mathbf{F} = G \int_{\Omega} \delta \frac{\mathbf{x}}{||\mathbf{x}||^3} \mathrm{d}V \,."$$ A few paragraphs earlier, the meaning of the multiple integral of a vector-valued function $\mathbf{f}\colon \Omega (\subseteq \mathbf{R}^n) \to \mathbf{R}^m$ is defined: "Assuming each of the component functions $f_1,\dots, f_m$ is integrable on $\Omega$, we set
$$\int_\Omega \mathbf{f} \mathrm{d}V = \begin{bmatrix}
\int_\Omega f_1 \mathrm{d}V\\
\vdots \\
\int_\Omega f_m \mathrm{d}V
\end{bmatrix} \,."$$
My question is: how do I proceed if I want to calculate the gravitational force exerted by a curve $C$ with linear mass density $\lambda(\mathbf{x})$? My guess is that I should compute the path integral for each component function, so that
$$\mathbf{F} = G \int_{C} \lambda \frac{\mathbf{x}}{||\mathbf{x}||^3} \mathrm{d}\ell = G \int_C \mathbf{f} \mathrm{d}\ell = G  \begin{bmatrix}
\int_C f_1 \mathrm{d}\ell\\
\vdots \\
\int_C f_m \mathrm{d}\ell
\end{bmatrix} = G \begin{bmatrix}
\int_{a}^b \,  f_1(\mathbf{g}(t)) \, ||\mathbf{g}'(t)|| \, \mathrm{d}t\\
\vdots \\
\int_{a}^b \,  f_m(\mathbf{g}(t)) \, ||\mathbf{g}'(t)|| \, \mathrm{d}t
\end{bmatrix} \,,$$
given a parametrization $\mathbf{g} \colon [a, b] \to \mathbf{R}^n$ for $C$. Is that correct?

Yes, your last equations are correct, though lookout for units since you're actually calculating the gravitational field at some point due to the whole curve. Or maybe $G$ is defined as the gravitational constant per unit mass?

Thanks! Oh, yes, I forgot to mention. Shifrin assumes a test mass with m = 1, so at the end of the day I'm actually calculating the field, not the force.

The principle here is that you can find the vector valued integral by component by component integration of the vector valued integrand. This is a line integral. Another approach is to set up a line integral to find the electric potential, then find the field by taking the gradient. So instead of an integral for each component, you execute one integral then differentiate for each component.

Yes, you want to compute a line integral (which comes in the next chapter of the book). More generally, you can do the same thing with any submanifold once you've learned how to integrate over a submanifold; there is a subtlety that you will need an "area form" for that submanifold. The cases of curves and surfaces are done explicitly in the next chapter, and you can generalize based on the discussion of surface area in section 4.2 of Chapter 8.
